# How close to an old mount point can I mount a TV?

Tags: walls, safety, television, mount

I recently purchased a house and the previous owners had a TV mounted over the fireplace, but removed the mount and painted over the holes before they sold. I would like to mount a TV, but unfortunately for me, the old mount was in the perfect spot, so I will have to move up or down. How close can I get to the old mount point before I run the risk of creating an unstable or dangerous mount?

[image]

Comment: Why do you have to move it? Is there no framing at that location, where hollow-wall anchors are needed?

Comment: There are many who say that there is _nowhere_ above a fireplace that's a "perfect spot" for a TV. There's heat coming out of the fireplace that's likely bad for electronics.

Comment: @isherwood, because I assume that reusing the holes, even if I somehow found the same kind of mount, would be unstable and loose.

Comment: That's simply not true. Lumber doesn't disintegrate like other materials when threaded fasteners are removed.

Comment: Thats good to know. But saying I can't find the right size bolts or whatever, how close can I drill the new holes and maintain the integrity of the framing?